# Add the sum of textViews from different activities

Tags: android

`Activity1` - total marks of `Activity1` stored in `textView1`
`Activity2` - total marks of `Activity2` stored in `textView2`
`Activity3` - sum of values of `textView1` and `textView2` stored in `textView3`

How can I get the sum of `textView1` and `textView2` to appear in `textView3`?

Comment: You can't really reference variables across Activities without some persistent storage. `SharedPreferences` would probably work, but you might want to add some code with an [edit] to clarify your question

Comment: You could create an abstract class in where you keep the count of the results of the different textviews and then use a get method to get the result in textview3

Comment: you can pass data to activities via intent

Answer (score 0):

You just take a public static variable in activity 1 and activity to and stored the value of text view in that variables. And access these variable in the activity 3 by getting instance of activity 1 or 2.

example:-

```
Activity 1:-

public static String textview1_value;

textview1_value = textview1.getText().toString;

Activity 2:-

public static String textview2_value;

textview2_value = textview2.getText().toString;

//Now in Activity 3 onCreate methode:-


//sum contains the sum of textview1 and textview2 values
int sum = Integer.parse(Activity1.textview1_value)+Integer.parse(Activity2.textview2_value);
```

Comment: if (radioButton_correct1a.isChecked()) {
                                            score++;
                                            scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(score));

                                        }
                                        if (radioButton_correct1b.isChecked()) {
                                            score++;
                                            scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(score));
how get value to activity 3 ?